# $k$ derivatives of $f(x)^p$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives

Given a function $F(x) = f(x)^p$ where $p$ is some non-integer power and all derivatives of $f$ are well-defined, I'd like to compute $F^{(k)}(x)$, where $(k)$ denotes the $k$th total derivative.

I tried to do this recursively, but I don't see the pattern. I get:
$$ F'(x) = p f^{p-1}f'$$
$$ F''(x) = p(p-1)f^{p-2}f'^2+pf^{p-1}f''$$
$$ F'''(x) = p(p-1)(p-2)f^{p-3}f'^3 + 3p(p-1)f^{p-2}f'f'' + pf^{p-1}f'''$$
$$ F^{(4)}(x) = p(p-1)(p-2)(p-3)f^{p-4}f'^4 + p(p-1)(p-2)f^{p-3}4f'^3f'' \dots$$

Any guidance, tricks (can I differentiate the $\log$?), or a closed form for this expression (probably involving binomial coefficients?) would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I guess the [Faà di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula) is what you are looking for.

Take $f(x)=x^p$ and you will find what you want.